# Getting HTTP 406 while calling external site from within servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, http-status-code-406

I have the following code in my servlet:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
public void doIt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    URL url = new URL("http://some.url.that.works.well.nl/q=hello&ie=nl&cx=hdyehgfyegywjehdkwed:7364du7");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));  // This line is generating the error
    String line = "";
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        pw.println(line);
    } 
}
```

running this servlet in tomcat gives me an http 406 error.

What I try to do is from within my servlet call google site search and I would like to parse the receieved (XML) result. (For now I just print te received result).
Trying the url in a browser is giving the correct result.

What am I missing here?

Kind regards,
Werner

Comment: HTTP 406 stands for not acceptable. Could you try ading the accept header for XML to your connection? conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/xml")

Comment: Tried that already. No change in the output. Still getting 406 error. tried various Capitalization of the wordt accept as I don't know if that could be the problem. The result stays the same.

Answer (score 4):

A 406 HTTP error means that the server couldn't build a response to your request with an acceptable content type. It means that your `URLConnection` asks the server for a given content type, and the server can't find an appropriate one.

You can change the content type requested by your `URLConnection` using the [`setRequestProperty(String, String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. You will have to add something like:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "text/xml");
```

(This supposes the server sends XML back to you)

Comment: It is sending back XML. Tried your solution but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.
I used wireshark to investigate what was send across the wire.
My url contained a space and that was causing all the problems.

As told before I wanted to contact google search and my url looked something like:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=golden handpressure&ie=8758438&cx=hjfweufhweufwef:9e
```

this is working in the browser address bar but not in java.

With wireshark I found out that my request header contained:

```
Request URI: http://www.google.com/search?q=golden
Request version: handpressure&ie=8758438&cx=hjfweufhweufwef:9e
```

This is ofcourse not correct. it should all be one field called 'Request URI'.
Changing the space into '%20' solved the problem.

Comment: Spot on. Many Libraries and tools (Like postman) encode the url internally so that , it works like right away. But some libraries do not encode the URL . So either you may have to find a library to encode URL or do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with Accept Headers. Can you check the accept-headers exchanged.

Comment: Hmmm. I will see if I can get my hands on a tool to see the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server for Content-Type response header. It should return :

```
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

charset=UTF-8 should be there in response. If not add it to header if server is in your control.